# Паттерн для instanceof

Tags: java

Есть несколько классов, далее идет проверка классов через instanceof, если передали такой класс тогда выполнить такие то действия.
Какой паттерн можно использовать.

```
getParams(SomeClass some) {

if (some instanceof SomeNoth) {
... 
... 
... 
... }
if (some instanceof SomeNoth2) {
... 
... 
... 
... }
if (some instanceof SomeNoth3) {
... 
... 
... 
... }
if (some instanceof SomeNoth4) {
... 
... 
... 
... }
if (some instanceof SomeNoth5) {
... 
... 
... 
... }
```

Comment: странное решение... но, если вам оно действительно надо... - чтобы не писать вот такое вот полотно, я бы посоветовал завести интерфейс, который хранил бы два метода void run(Object obj) и boolean isTypeof(Object obj). Далее, простое решение - делайте кучу классов-хандлеров, наследуете каждым классом этот интерфейс, в каждом методе isTypeof(Object obj) возвращаете ваш obj instanceof ..., в методе run - делаете что надо. Создать инициализацию коллекции экземпляров таких классов, например, singleton-ом, вы и сами сможете) В цикле останется перебрать, и проверить, что надо запускать, а что не надо

Comment: Если других, более интересных, вариантов никто не предложит, покажу пример

Comment: Действия какого плана? Если вызов каких-то методов у `some`, то тогда стоит создать интерфейс `SomeInterface`, сделать чтобы все нужные классы его реализовывали, в метод передавать `SomeInterface some`, после чего вызывать нужный метод (или методы) у `some` без всяких `if`-ов.

Comment: `switch(some.getClass().getSimpleName())` в виде костыля.

Comment: @test123 покажите пожалуйста пример

Comment: @JNat, готово. В рамках метода void run(Object obj), вы можете писать что угодно, любой обработчик, даже не обязательно связанный с тем классом что вы просканировали через instanceof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как вы настаиваете на примере, приведу простой для понимания.
Наши тестовые классы:

```
public class Test1 {
    public void method1() { System.out.print("Test1.method1"); }
}

public class Test2 {
    public void method2() { System.out.print("Test2.method2"); }
}
```

Далее, небольшая архитектура:

```
public interface IHandler {

    void run(Object obj);

    boolean isTypeof(Object obj);

}
```

Под неё делаем две реализации хандлеров:

```
public class Test1Handler implements IHandler {

    @Override
    public void run(Object obj){
        Test1 test = (Test1)obj;
        // Здесь любой код...
        test.method1(); // для примера
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTypeof(Object obj){
        return obj instanceof Test1;
    }

}

public class Test2Handler implements IHandler {

    @Override
    public void run(Object obj){
        Test2 test = (Test2)obj;
        // Здесь любой код...
        test.method2(); // для примера
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTypeof(Object obj){
        return obj instanceof Test2;
    }

}
```

Всё, архитектура готова, реализация есть, теперь можно всё свернуть в один универсальный метод:

```
public class ServiceChecker {

    private static ServiceChecker instance;

    private List<IHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<IHandler>();

    public ServiceChecker(){
        handlers.add(new Test1Handler());
        handlers.add(new Test2Handler());
    }

    public static ServiceChecker getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance = new ServiceChecker();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void check(Object some){
        for(IHandler handler : handlers){
            if(handler.isTypeof(some)){
                handler.run(some);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Теперь можно смело использовать:

```
ServiceChecker.getInstance().check(new Test2());
ServiceChecker.getInstance().check(new Test1());
```

Что вообще этот подход вам даст:

1. Вы разделите ваше полотно на кучу классов, что в разы удобнее содержать и дополнять.
2. Вы сможете составить огромную "библиотеку" хандлеров. Лично я такое использовал для преобразования типов в Unity3d, своего рода универсальный парсер. Универсальный он потому, что добавлять и удалять хандлеры не составляет труда, как вы заметили.

Является ли это паттерном? Честно скажу - я не знаю. Скорее всего, нечто такое уже придумали.

Comment: При поддержке будет достаточно сложно понять, что речь шла о `getParams`

Comment: @hardsky, да и в целом, решение довольно громоздкое. ИМХО, самое отличное решение показал [Александр Мартынцев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/241790/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80-%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b2), надо будет мне самому взять на вооружение :D

Comment: @test123 Да реализовать свой класс для каждого класса лучше, плюс  прямо в классе описываю какой instanceof подходит, имхо меньше шансов ошибиться. а HashMap применять если здесь проблема с производительностью

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать изящно и красиво - использовать фабрику. А именно:

```
Map<Class, Runnable> actions = new HashMap<>();  
....  
void registrationAction(Class<?> cl, Runnable action){
   actions.put(cl, action);
}

void actionOn(SomeClass cl){
   actions.get(cl.getClass()).run();
}
```

Comment: Не является ли это костылем?

Comment: @JNat, нет, не является. Хм, причём, довольно простое решение))

Comment: Вообще это общепринято. Если у вас вдруг появится новый класс, вам не надо будет дописывать свой код. Вам просто надо будет зарегистрировать новый обработчик (особенно это удобно если у вас будут плагины). Более того - мы у себя используем автоматическую регистрацию обработчиков - просто аннотируем класс, а сканер его укладывает в подобную в ответе структуру.

Comment: @JNat, С огромной долей вероятности, карта будет быстрее. + Её скрость можно менять реализацией, а instanceof - изменять не получится... Рефлексия, как ни крути, медленная штука.

Comment: HasMap будет быстрее. Он просто возьмет имя класса (строка) и за константную сложность О(1) выполнит любой запрос.

Answer (score 5):

Начиная с Java 7 можно использовать `String` в `switch`, следовательно можно хакнуть так:

```
getParams(SomeClass some) {
   String clzName=some.getClass().getSimpleName();
   switch(clzName) {
      case "SomeNoth":
        break;
      case "SomeNoth2":
        break;
      //blah-blah
   }
}
```

**Update**

Для поборников чистоты можно сделать так:

```
interface Doable {
    public void doSome();
}

class ExSomeClass extends SomeClass implements Doable {
    public void doSome() {
        //blah-blah
    }
}

class ExSomeNoth extends SomeNoth implements Doable {
    public void doSome() {
        //blah-blah
    }
}

class ExSomeNoth2 extends SomeNoth2 implements Doable {
    public void doSome() {
        //blah-blah
    }
}
```

В итоге ваш метод будет работать так:

```
getParams(Doable some) {
   some.doSome();
}
```

Никаких кастов, `instanceof` и упаси боже модификации исходных классов.

Comment: А есть ли в этом смысл? От полотна кода вы не избавитесь.

Comment: Поскольку классы библиотечные, то внедрение интерфейса не сработает, ну разве что творить обертки над ними - но тогда кода будет еще больше. `switch` всяко разно лучше лесенки `if/else if`

Comment: Так лучше) Но, опять же, автор пояснил, что он не сможет отнаследовать ваш интерфейс в нужных ему классах, потому что они - части библиотеки, которая, как я понимаю, для него - чёрный ящик, ну, или, просто недоступна для правки.

Comment: Причем тут это? Классы он создает сам, так что может как угодно отнаследовать

Comment: если всё как вы говорите, то у ТС неверно поставлен вопрос. Это в корне всё меняет.

Answer (score 2):

Что бы действовать подобным образом, надо иметь очень веские на то причины. Стандартным решением будет объявить интерфейс с методом `getParams` и имплиментировать его для всех ваших классов.

```
public interface SomeNothInterface{
    public Params getParams();
}

public class SomeNoth implements SomeNothInterface{
....
    public Params getParams(){
        //логика
    }
```

И вызывать так

```
public Params getParams(SomeNothInterface someClass) {
    return someClass.getParams();
}
```

Comment: так не получится сделать потому что классы из библиотеки

Comment: @JNat вот было бы здорово, если бы в тексте вопросов не пропускали столь важные моменты...

Comment: @JNat между ними есть что-то общее или прямо совсем разные классы? Посмотрите, возможно они и так интерфейс один реализуют

Comment: Либо врапперы над классами с необходимой доп логикой

Comment: @JNat я вам рекомендую задать новый вопрос с описанием глобальной задачи. Велика вероятность, что вы пытаетесь закручивать гвозди отверткой

Comment: @hardsky да, я тоже про wrapper-ы подумал. Непонятно только чем в данной ситуации является `SomeClass`.

Comment: @Regent на самом деле без разницы что именно скрывается за SomeClass, если нужно просто по разному getParams сформировать.

Comment: @rjhdby, тоже не исключаю что это именно так и есть. Но, конкретно этот вопрос - решаемый.

Answer (score 2):

У вас тут самый настоящий антипаттерн. Правильный объектно-ориентированный код работает с максимально узкой абстракцией и ему не требуется проверять конкретный тип. Если такая необходимость вдруг появилась, значит вы нарушаете принципы [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). К тому же, `instanceof` ещё и медленный оператор.

Comment: Что досталось, это либа

Comment: Обожаю такие ответы :) - выглядит как возмущение автомобилиста - что на дорогах не должно быть ям - но они то ведь есть и будут - мир то ведь неидеален...

Comment: @Barmaley не отрицаю, что иногда без проверки типа не обойтись, но надо стремиться избегать таких ситуаций. И воспитывать это стремление в начинающих.

Comment: Посмотрите на апдейт моего ответа - без антипаттерна :)

Comment: @Barmaley я его даже плюсанул. Как и многие другие ваши ответы :)